# Sorting Files and Folders using month

Tags: python, automation, directory

I'm looking for a code that moves all the Folders in a directory with the specified year.

For example : I have monthly issues of books of several years in a directory with corresponding month name on them. i.e., "June-2015" folder will contain the June 2015 Issue of the book. All I need is a program that moves the Issues of 2015 into a folder called "2015" which contains the Issues from "Jan-2015 to Dec-2015".

Comment: *"I'm looking for a code"* - we're here to neither find it nor write it for you.

Answer (score 0):

Try a package like [`os`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html) or [`shutil`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/shutil.html)